# How to merge two auth providers of firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am First registering a new user using email id and password. In login page, I have added login with email id and password and authentication with google. When I am logging in with email id and password it is working perfectly but when I am logging in with the google with same email id I get logged in but then it updates the auth provider to google. And then I am no longer be able to login using same email id and password. It is giving the error message `User does not exist or user does not have a password`. My question is how to merge the two auth providers so that if I log in using google then also it should get logged in but if again I log in with same email id then I should be able to log in using the email id and password also.

This is the code of the login Activity.

```
open class LogInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private lateinit var oneTapClient: SignInClient

    companion object {
        private const val RC_SIGN_IN = 123
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in)

        auth = Firebase.auth
        oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this)

        btn_logIn.setOnClickListener {
            signInWithEmailPass()
        }

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        tv_forgotPass.setOnClickListener {
            forgotPassword()
        }

        linear_layout.setOnClickListener {
            signInWithGoogle()
        }

        tv_register.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SignUp::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun forgotPassword() {
        val intent = Intent(this, ResetPassword::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun signInWithGoogle() {
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            progressBar_LI.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try{
            if(task.isSuccessful) {
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                Log.d(TAG, "FirebaseAuthWithGoogle " + account.id)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken)
            } else {
                progressBar_LI.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        } catch (e: ApiException){
            Log.w(TAG, "SignInResult: Failed Code = " + e.statusCode )
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String?) {

        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            val auth = auth.signInWithCredential(credential).await()
            //update UI in main thread because we can not update it in io thread
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                updateUI()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun signInWithEmailPass() {
        progressBar_LI.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        val email = et_email_LA.editText?.text.toString()
        val pass = et_password_LA.editText?.text.toString()

        if(email.isNotEmpty() && pass.isNotEmpty()) {
            if(pass.length < 8){
                et_password_LA.error = "Password must contains at least 8 characters!"
                et_password_LA.requestFocus()
                progressBar_LI.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        updateUI()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, it.exception?.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show()
                        progressBar_LI.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Empty fields!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            progressBar_LI.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        if (currentUser != null) {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    private fun updateUI() {
        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you consider at some point in time using [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), then I recommend you check this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d). Here is the [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle) and this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) with the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication has the concept of a preferred provider, which means recognizes when a certain email address signs in with a certain provider. The most common example of this is when you sign in to Google with a @gmail.com address, or to Microsoft with a @outlook.com or @hotmail.com address. Even if such an email address was used with another provider before, the preferred provider is trusted to know the account better and so the previously existing account gets overwritten.

If you instead want to be able to sign in both with email+password and with the preferred provider, you should [link the accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) instead. To link accounts, you first look up whether there's an existing provider for the email address the user entered by calling [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail). If you get any result, follow the flow to link the providers to the same account. If you get no results, complete the normal sign-in flow for a new account.